# Different tocdepth for main toc and in-section toc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Having code like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A long section}
\startcontents[section]
\printcontents[section]{}{2}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{SubA}
\subsubsection{SSub-a}
\subsection{SubB}
\subsubsection{SSub-b}
\subsection{SubC}
\end{document}
```

I want to skip sub- and subsubsections for section `A long section` in a main TOC but have them present in a section toc. Wrapping the section with `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` and `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}` hides `A long section`'s structure from main toc but makes it's own toc disappear completely. How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, `titletoc` writes partial ToCs to a file with extension `.ptc`; you can then set the `tocdepth` counter to the appropriate values (for the main ToC using `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` and for the partial ToC using using `\addtocontents{ptc}{...}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\section{A long section}
\startcontents[section]
\printcontents[section]{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{SubA}
\subsubsection{SSub-a}
\subsection{SubB}
\subsubsection{SSub-b}
\subsection{SubC}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! that's exactly what i wanted

Comment: And would it be possible to have one global tableofcontents for the sections only, then one partial tableofcontents for the subsections only, and finally one partial tableofcontents for subsubsections only?

Comment: @pluton yes; it's possible using `\startcontents[...]`, `\resumecontents[...]`. Perhaps you could ask this in a new question?

Answer (score 1):

In response to my own comment on Gonzalo's post, a slight modification to his solution works with the `mathtools` and `mhchem` package:

```
\startcontents[section]
\printcontents[section]{}{2}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
```

Note the only change from the MWE above is that I have removed `\addcontents{ptc}` and the extra set of curly braces from `setcounter` in the `\printcontents` command.

I have used this solution both in an `article` and a `book` documentclass with no problems.