# Mimic memoir ToC layout in titletoc output

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, line-spacing, titletoc

I with the help of a previous answer on here [Different tocdepth for main toc and in-section toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60123/different-tocdepth-for-main-toc-and-in-section-toc), I have made it so my `titletoc` is able to contain `subsections` while my main `toc` does not have them.  However, I noticed that the formatting for the `titletoc` toc has different spacing.

If I had set the main `toc` format myself, I would copy the parameters to mimic them for the `titletoc` toc.  But since it is the default memoir format, I'm not sure how to replicate it.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus2pt}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setpnumwidth{2.5em}
\setrmarg{3.5em}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}    
\chapter{Chap1}
\section{Chap1Sec1}
\section{Chap1Sec2}
\chapter{Chap2}
\section{Chap2Sec1}
\section{Chap2Sec2}
\subsection{Chap2Sec2Subsec1}
\chapter{Chap3}
\settocdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
\section{Chap3Sec1}
\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec2}

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\stopcontents
\section{Chap3Sec3}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec4}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec5}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec6}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec7}\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{9}
\chapter{Chap4}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\section{Chap4Sec1}\clearpage
\section{Chap4Sec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap4Sec2Subsec1}

\end{document}
```

Here is a 2nd MWE showing the suggestion by lockstep, and now the new spacing issue.  It uses the `DoubleSpacing` and `SingleSpacing` use as well from the `memoir` package

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus2pt}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setpnumwidth{2.5em}
\setrmarg{3.5em}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection} 
\mainmatter
\DoubleSpacing   
\chapter{Chap1}
\section{Chap1Sec1}
\section{Chap1Sec2}
\chapter{Chap2}
\section{Chap2Sec1}
\section{Chap2Sec2}
\subsection{Chap2Sec2Subsec1}
\SingleSpacing
\chapter{Chap3}
\settocdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
\section{Chap3Sec1}
\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec2}
\bigskip
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\stopcontents
\section{Chap3Sec3}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec4}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec5}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec6}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec7}\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{9}
\chapter{Chap4}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\section{Chap4Sec1}\clearpage
\section{Chap4Sec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap4Sec2Subsec1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the `\parskip` length to 12pt, and it seems that -- contrary to the normal ToC -- the partial ToC is affected hereby. Workaround: Issue

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
```

at the start of the document body. Additonally, you might want to add some vertical space (e.g., `\bigskip`) before the start of the partial ToC.

EDIT: In your second MWE, you switch (for whatever reason) from `\DoubleSpacing` to `\SingleSpacing` mid-document, and *both* settings affect the ToC resp. the partial ToC. I suggest to add, e.g., `\protect\OnehalfSpacing` to the `.toc` file.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus2pt}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setpnumwidth{2.5em}
\setrmarg{3.5em}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection} 
\mainmatter
\DoubleSpacing   
\chapter{Chap1}
\section{Chap1Sec1}
\section{Chap1Sec2}
\chapter{Chap2}
\section{Chap2Sec1}
\section{Chap2Sec2}
\subsection{Chap2Sec2Subsec1}
\SingleSpacing
\chapter{Chap3}
\settocdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter-\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
\section{Chap3Sec1}
\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec2}
\bigskip
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec1}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec3}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Chap3Sec2Subsec4}
\stopcontents
\section{Chap3Sec3}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec4}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec5}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec6}\clearpage
\section{Chap3Sec7}\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{9}
\chapter{Chap4}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\section{Chap4Sec1}\clearpage
\section{Chap4Sec2}\clearpage
\subsection{Chap4Sec2Subsec1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it appears that the space is too small compared to the normal TOC

Comment: @JM Which space in the normal ToC do you refer to?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sorry it seems in the MWE it is correct, however in my full document, the skip between lines of the partial TOC are now very compressed compared to the rest of my document.  In the memoir package I am using the \SingleSpacing command, and am wondering if that is affecting the output.  I've updated my original post to show how I pull together the sections of my document.  I'm trying compiling it with the doublespacing and singlespacing components commented out

Comment: @JM You need to provide a compilable example (i.e., one that doesn't  `\input` files not available to others) that shows the problematic behaviour.

Comment: I understand, I'll try and work on getting one available to you shortly.  I did just compile my work, removing the two commands `DoubleSpacing` and `SingleSpacing`, and the spacing in the two TOCs are the same.  So I am quite sure that it is how `memoir` is implementing me using the `SingleSpacing` command.  I'll try and get the example up soon

Comment: I've added a new MWE showing how the `DoubleSpacing` and `SingleSpacing` commands are impacting the layout.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I switch to SingleSpacing for the SI section.  Especially for my code sections, and the tables, I don't need/want the extra spacing.